# updating a listadapter

Tags: android, listadapter

i can't update data in my listAdapter in android

*my adapter:*

```
class Adapter(val viewModel: ConfirmViewModel,
              private val uiDownloadManager: UiDownloadManager)
    : ListAdapter<Comment, RecyclerView.ViewHolder>(MessageListDiffUtil()) {

    override fun onCreateViewHolder(parent: ViewGroup, viewType: Int): RecyclerView.ViewHolder {
        val viewItem = LayoutInflater.from(parent.context)
                .inflate(R.layout.confirm_comment, parent, false)
        return CommentHolder(viewItem)
    }

    override fun onBindViewHolder(viewHolder: RecyclerView.ViewHolder, position: Int) {
        try {
            viewHolder as CommentHolder
            viewHolder.bind(getItem(position), uiDownloadManager)
        } catch (e: Exception) {
            e.printStackTrace()
        }
    }

}

class MessageListDiffUtil : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Comment>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(p0: Comment, p1: Comment): Boolean {
        return p0.serverId == p1.serverId
    }
    override fun areContentsTheSame(p0: Comment, p1: Comment): Boolean {
        return p0.serverId == p1.serverId
    }
}
```

update code:

```
val c = Comment()
c.serverId = 5
c.text = "for test"
val l = listOf(c)
adapter.submitList(l)
```

don't shows me any data in recyclerview 
What's happening is when submitList is called the first time the adapter don't renders all the items

Comment: No, in ListAdapter you don't need to use notifyDataSetChanged()

Answer (score 0):

I think it has something to do with your Diff item callback try to add more compares not just id. Something like this

```
class MessageListDiffUtil : DiffUtil.ItemCallback<Comment>() {
    override fun areItemsTheSame(p0: Comment, p1: Comment): Boolean {
        return p0.serverId == p1.serverId && p0.something == p1.something ......
    }
    override fun areContentsTheSame(p0: Comment, p1: Comment): Boolean {
        return p0.serverId == p1.serverId && p0.commentText == p1.commentText .....
    }
}
```

also on some cases it is needed to override submitList() in ListAdapter:

```
 override fun submitList(list: List<SomeModel>?) {
        if (list != null) {
            super.submitList(ArrayList(list))
        } else {
            super.submitList(null)
        }
    }
```

Comment: i use breakpoint to `override fun areItemsTheSame(p0: Comment, p1: Comment): Boolean {
        return p0.serverId == p1.serverId && p0.something == p1.something ......
    }` but dosn't fire

Comment: what about areContentsTheSame?

Comment: omg my recyclerview is null . before my fragment be create i try to find recyclerview on view. thank's for help me